# Spring Data, lazy загрузка связанной сущности

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, jpa

Есть две сущности Тема (Topic) и ответы для неё (Answer). Правильно ли работает Lazy?

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "answer")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Answer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column (name="answer_name")
private String answerName;

@Column (name="count_voices")
private int countVoice;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_topic")
private Topic topic;

public Answer() {
    super();
}
}
```

И сущность Topic:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "topic")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Topic {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column (name = "id_topic")
private Long id;
private String topicName;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Answer> answer;
}
```

Получаю все записи из таблицы Topic:

```
@Service
public class TopicServiceImpl implements TopicService{

@Autowired
private TopicRepository topicRepository;

@Override
public Topic findById(long id) {
    return topicRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteTopicById(long id) {
    topicRepository.delete(id);     
}

@Override
public List<Topic> findAllTopics() {
    return topicRepository.findAll();
}
```

1) Когда делаю вызов findAll, то вытягиваются все Topic со связанными Answer. Разве так должно быть?

2) Как сделать, что бы findall возвращало только Topic, а не тянуло еще и Answer для каждой записи? 
    Если я правильно понимаю, то Answer должен тянуться, когда будет вызван findOne? Как оптимально сделать код, как делают в продакшене, объясните?

результат findAll():

```html
{
"id": 1,
"topicName": "Хочешь сладких апельсинов?",
"startDate": 1486872742000,
"endDate": null,
"answerList": [
  {
"id": 1,
"answerName": "Да",
"countVoice": 7,
"topic": 1
},
  {
"id": 2,
"answerName": "Нет",
"countVoice": 2,
"topic": 1
},
  {
"id": 3,
"answerName": "У меня на них аллергия",
"countVoice": 1,
"topic": 1
}
],
}
```

ссылка на проект gitHub [Код](https://github.com/disaer88/voting-application.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lazy` - ленивый. В данном случае ленивая загрузка. Значит, что список `answer-ов` будет загружен только при обращении к полю. Пока его никто не трогает, ничего не произойдёт.

Это никак не связано ни с `findAll`, ни с `findOne`. Как видно из названия методов:
`findAll` загрузит список всех `topic-ов`
`findOne` выдаст только одного из них (если сможет конечно:).

Они сами по себе не приводят к загрузке или не загрузке чего бы то ни было, связанного с topic-ами.

И в том и другом случае будут получены topic-и/topic, у которых список answer-ов не загружен.

Так откуда они взялись в Вашем выводе? Элементарно, Ватсон!
Процедура, которая готовит Ваш json, пробегает по всем полям topic-а, в том числе и по `answer`, что и приводит к его загрузке!

Просто не трогайте `List<Answer> answer` когда не надо и всё.
(как заставить процедуру подготовки json обходить его стороной - ищите сами)

Кстати, отношения `XxxToMany` по умолчанию подразумевают `fetch Lazy`. Можно сэкономить не наборе лишних букв.

Comment: List<Topic> topics = topicService.findAllTopics(); все что делается в RestController. В последней строке первого поста есть ссылка на Git, там в папке controller лежит единственный класс RestController. Можно убедится что я не дергаю. Спасибо кстати за совет с Lazy, другим может будет полезно, а я пока разбираюсь уже сам нашел, что это свойство по умолчанию.

Comment: Вы не трогаете - `ResponseEntity` трогает.